# Function returns a null when its not supposed to?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a warranty function (which is being used for an `INSERT` query) that determines whether a warranty is still valid. It compares `warranty_remaining` (`DATEDIFF` between the date of purchase and today's date) with `warranty_duration` (3 years aka the warranty duration), if the `warranty_remaining` is less than or equal to the warranty duration then it should return the `warranty_remaining` as expected. Else, it will return a null indicating the warranty has expired.

However, there seems to be an error, as I get a `NULL` returned in the warranty row. After I run my `INSERT` query, every value is expected except for warranty. I suspect the issue lies in the way/format the `warranty_remaining` is being returned after the IF block. I say this because I've tried testing the if statement/calculations above the return statement (`RETURN @warranty_remaining;`) to check if its working as expected. (i.e., I changed the return statement to return 1000 instead of @ `warranty_remaining`. In the end, it did show 1000 in the warranty row. Which tells me it shouldn't be a logic / calculation error in the code).

Another possibility would be how the function is being called in the `INSERT` query but it seems pretty slim.

**Notes:**

- Whenever I wanted to test changes to the function, I deleted always deleted the existing instance in the Programmability/Functions/Scalar-valued Functions beforehand
- The datatype of warranty is int, hence it shouldn't be a datatype mismatch since the function has `RETURNS INT`
- PK is `product_id` and I set `Is Identity` to Yes
- Assume warranty is 3 years
- If the function truly can't work then I guess it has to be carried out in the individual VALUES

Code for function:

```
USE YourDatabaseName; -- Replace 'YourDatabaseName' with the actual name of your database

-- Start a new batch
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CalculateWarranty 
    (@purchase_date DATE)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @warranty_duration INT;
    DECLARE @warranty_remaining INT;

    -- Set the warranty duration to 3 years (in days)
    SET @warranty_duration = 1095;

    -- Calculate the remaining warranty duration in days
    SET @warranty_remaining = DATEDIFF(DAY, @purchase_date, GETDATE());

    -- If the remaining warranty is within 3 years, return the remaining duration; otherwise, return NULL
    IF @warranty_remaining <= @warranty_duration
        RETURN @warranty_remaining;

    -- Default return statement (return NULL if warranty is not within 3 years)
    RETURN NULL;        
END;
```

Code for `INSERT` query:

```
INSERT INTO product(supplier_id, category_id, serial_no,
    product_brand, product_name, purchase_price,
    purchase_date, warranty, description) 
VALUES (1, 1, 'PF-2HKJ16',
        'Lenovo', 'ThinkPad X1 Carbon 8 / i7-10510U', NULL, -- Enter purchase_price later,
        '2021-11-01',
        dbo.CalculateWarranty(CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())), -- Call function called CaclulateWarranty
        'The ThinkPad X1 Carbon 8th generation with an Intel Core i7-10510U processor is a premium ultrabook laptop developed by Lenovo. It is designed to deliver exceptional performance, portability, and durability for professionals and business users.');
```

Comment: FYI for performance reasons you would be much better off creating an inline table valued function.

Comment: Further FYI, SSMS is just a client interface, its unrelated to the database engine its connected to. You want to provide `select @@version` instead.

Comment: Your function works, well sort of, it will certainly never return a null when you pass it todays date e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/s3u21Yly

Comment: However I think your logic is flawed, because `DATEDIFF(DAY, @purchase_date, GETDATE());` returns 0 - which is wrong, because you don't have 0 days remaining on your purchase date.

Comment: You mean there's a logical flaw because I'm returning the warranty_remaining? Because the logic makes sense to me (ie., warranty_remaining refers to the number of  days elapsed from the purchase_date and today's date. After which if it exceed 3 years, then return the warranty_remaining else return null).

Comment: Bear in mind `DATEDIFF` returns the number of date *boundaries* crossed between those two values. It maybe more or less than what you were expecting

Comment: Well if that makes sense to you :) if I buy a product AFAIAC there are 3 years of warranty remaining, not 0. The clue is in the name "remaining" how many days remain before my warranty runs out, its certainly not zero. What you are counting `warranty used` for want of a better term.

Comment: But anyway, your question states you are getting null when you don't expect it. However that doesn't appear to be possible with the example provided. So please provide a [mre] which demonstrated the null.

Comment: How do you suggest I provide this? Because I basically have all the code pasted above, would images/videos help?

Comment: No, I gave you a link to a DBFiddle which shows that you code works... so you now need to provide a DBFiddle showing it not working, because you are clearly doing something that isn't obvious from your question.

Comment: I assume you don't have any triggers on your table?

Comment: Further fiddle showing it works exactly as your requirements suggest it should work. https://dbfiddle.uk/S8J9LOrj

Comment: I don't know what a trigger is but I don't believe so. Hope this illustrates it well enough DBFIddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/o35f31cn

Comment: Warranty is 0? You said its turning up as null? There is no null there. (Also you are showing a decimal which is a strange datatype). 0 is the correct value according to your logic, if you buy something today, you are comparing that date with, today, therefore there are zero days inbetween. I you are not expecting 0 then my original statement about your logic being reversed is correct.

Comment: Seriously the naming of your variable is confusing `@warranty_remaining = DATEDIFF(DAY, @purchase_date, GETDATE());`. What you have calculate is no of days since purchase_date.  `warranty_remaining` should be `= purchase_date + warranty_duration - getdate()`.

Comment: I mean meant to use int but the decimal got there because I wanted to experiment with representing the warranty left (i.e., with more specific values like x years instead of days). But I always though null equals to 0 for int? Regardless I think what you said was correct, I got the logic reversed but how would I reference the purchase_date(i.e., '2023-02-27')? Because I can't seem to reference its name directly and I have quite a few columns to insert so it would be tedious to do manual copy-pasting.

Comment: @Squirrel Completely agree, I'll probably try to figure a way to do purchase_date + warranty_duration - getdate(), since that's would be what accurately represents warranty_remaining.

Comment: NULL and zero are two very different things. NULL means unknown and is a very special value in SQL. Zero is just a fixed number as are 1, 2, 3, etc. Google NULL, if you are not familiar with the concept.

Answer (score 0):

you can test the function only by calling it and adding some Dates

The flaw is that you have to handle NULL and you need to subtract the remainding time from the warranty duration

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CalculateWarranty (
    @purchase_date DATE
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @warranty_duration INT;
    DECLARE @warranty_remaining INT;

    -- Set the warranty duration to 3 years (in days)
    SET @warranty_duration = 1095;
    IF @purchase_date Is NULL 
       return -1
      
    -- Calculate the remaining warranty duration in days
    SET @warranty_remaining = DATEDIFF(DAY, @purchase_date, GETDATE());

    -- If the remaining warranty is within 3 years, return the remaining duration; otherwise, return NULL
    IF @warranty_remaining <= @warranty_duration
        RETURN @warranty_duration - @warranty_remaining;

    -- Default return statement (return NULL if warranty is not within 3 years)
    RETURN NULL;        
END;
```

```
select dbo.CalculateWarranty(NULL);
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| -1 |

```
select dbo.CalculateWarranty(GETdate());
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| 1095 |

```
select dbo.CalculateWarranty(DATEADD(day,-5,GETdate()));
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| 1090 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z9ci_8x7)

To adress your problem, there are only 2 posibilies in your function to return NULL

You pass NULL as Value or you have a pirchase_day the is earlier than the 1095 days.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CalculateWarranty (
    @purchase_date DATE
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @warranty_duration INT;
    DECLARE @warranty_remaining INT;

    -- Set the warranty duration to 3 years (in days)
    SET @warranty_duration = 1095;

    -- Calculate the remaining warranty duration in days
    SET @warranty_remaining = DATEDIFF(DAY, @purchase_date, GETDATE());

    -- If the remaining warranty is within 3 years, return the remaining duration; otherwise, return NULL
    IF @warranty_remaining <= @warranty_duration
        RETURN @warranty_remaining;

    -- Default return statement (return NULL if warranty is not within 3 years)
    RETURN NULL;        
END;
```

```
select dbo.CalculateWarranty(DATEADD(DAY,-1098, getdate()));
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| *null* |

```
SELECT dbo.CalculateWarranty(CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| 0 |

```
select dbo.CalculateWarranty(NULL);
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7yI3GYVD)

Comment: OP seems to think it makes logical sense to return 0 when the item is purchased <shrug> but your answer doesn't explain how OP is getting nulls on initial insert (because I don't think its possible).